# R Shiny: Remove specific rows borders in table

Tags: css, shiny

I have created a table in R/Shiny with 7 rows where the 2nd and the 5th are blank (as the arrows indicate).

[image: Table]

I am trying to completely remove all vertical borders in rows 2 and 5 via css and finally present the table as having three seperate sections  The table's id is Statistics I and this is my attempt in css:

```
#StatisticsI table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#StatisticsI td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: normal;
      border: 1.9px solid #2e3658;
}
#StatisticsI th {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1.9px solid #2e3658;
}



#StatisticsI tr:nth-child(3), 
#StatisticsI tr:nth-child(6) {
    font-size: 120%;
    border: none;
}
```

The last section is my attempt to make this happen but unfortunatelly it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to remove border in specific rows.

```
td { border: 1px solid #000000; height: 10px; }

tr:nth-child(2) td, tr:nth-child(5) td {
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xx4quj0/